# Simplifying a Beamer overlay style

Tags: beamer

I am making a Beamer presentation, like say:

```
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{\Huge}\onslide<1->{Text 1.}
\begin{itemize}
\item<2->\only<2>{\Huge} Item 1.
\item<3->\only<3>{\Huge} Item 2.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

The goal is to make each slide present the currently introduced text in a huge font, while leaving the rest of the text visible but much smaller.

This works, but

(1) This requires a lot of writing commands per slide.

(2) Is quite fragile -- if I have to reorder things, I could potentially need to spend a lot of time renumbering.

Is there a way to make it do the same job while parsing a source that looks more like, for example,

```
\begin{frame}
Text 1.
\slide 
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1.
\item Item 2.
\end{itemize}
```

or perhaps with a minimal amount of extra commands to separate out the slides?

---

I don't have a lot of experience with creating commands, but experimented with this and it didn't work:

```
\newcounter{slidenum}
\setcounter{slidenum}{1} 
\newcommand{\next}[1]{\only<\theslidenum>{\Huge}\onslide<\theslidenum->{#1}\addtocounter{slidenum}{1}}
```

In the way that I imagine this working, I could put every next overlay in a `\next{...}` command and at the start of every frame, restart the counter.  But when I try to use it in a slide, the item in the `\next{...}` is neither made huge nor is it hidden on the first overlay.

Comment: +1 nice question. Next time, could you please add a complete minimal example? i.e., include the `\documentclass{article}` command and `\begin{document}`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following do what you want?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\hugeOnce}[1]{{\only<.>{\Huge} #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
\only<+->{\hugeOnce{Text 1.}}
\begin{itemize}
\item \hugeOnce{Item 1.}
\item \hugeOnce{Item 2.}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes it does!  It certainly solves the fagility problem.  It's a little more code than I was hoping to write per overlay, but it works quite well.  Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: @Addem That's great! Thanks for letting me know. Could you please give the other answer a try? It really is more elegant and practical (I think it would save some typing and keep your code cleaner).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a similar trick as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1334#a1579 and create a new beamer action:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{hugeenv}{\only{\Huge}}{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\only<+>{\Huge} Text
\begin{itemize}[<huge@+|+->]
\item Item 1.
\item Item 2.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and clean! I vote for this answer :).

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks! I like yours too, nice to understand what is is happening!

Comment: Depending on what the OP wants, I wonder if it would make sense to put the default overlay as the default overlay of the *frame*. Would there then be a simple way to rewrite the `\only` command (that could rely on the default overlay instead of repeating `\Huge`)?

Comment: @scottkosty I'm not sure I understand your comment, do you mean something like `\begin{frame}[<huge@+|+->]`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. And then I wonder if the `\only` can use that specification automatically. I tried and it didn't work. Don't spend time on it. I was just thinking it might simplify things a bit more but I'm not sure about that claim.

Comment: `\only` takes an overlay specification, my new `huge` action is not an overlay specification, but an action. You need a macro like `\item` which takes actions and not overlays.

Comment: @scottkosty What you could do would be something like `\begin{itemize}[<huge@+|+->]
\item[] Text
\item Item 1.
\item Item 2.
\end{itemize}`

Comment: Ah interesting trick! I never would have thought about that. Nice. Regarding actions vs. overlay specifications, I think it's time for me to finally dive into the Beamer manual. Thanks!

Comment: @scottkosty Section "9.6.3 Action Specifications" of the manual is looking forward to your visit :)

Comment: I'll come knocking soon! :)